# before pseudo-element covering inner content

Tags: html, css

so I have created a `div` as the parent with a `span` element inside, holding the title for the parent and I have defined a `css` before pseudo-element (`:before`) for the parent so when user hovers over the element it has a nice transition 
but the problem is : the `:before` covers the `span` element so the title gets hidden which is not acceptable of course !

here's the sample code on jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/msU6p/4/

here's the HTML :

```
<div class="menuItem_Large" id="node_1_menu">
    <span>menu item 1</span>
</div>
```

and styles :

```
.menuItem_Large
{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   display: inline-block;
   padding-left: 6px;
   padding-right: 6px;
   height: 20px;
   line-height: 16px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   background-image : url('http://i58.tinypic.com/21eyrk8.png');
   background-repeat: repeat;
   cursor:pointer;
}

.menuItem_Large:before
{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:0%;
    height:20px;
    background-color:rgba(0,200,255,1);
    transition:width 0.3s ease-out;
}

.menuItem_Large:hover:before
{
    width:100%;
}

.menuItem_Large span
{
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

- Please Note :

I tried using `z-index` on span setting it to 2 or so but It doesn't work and when I set `z-index` of `before` element to negative It goes under the parent's `background-image` which is not good

does anyone know where's my mistake or what can I possibly do to make this work only using `css` ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try opacity [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/msU6p/5/). Do you want this

Comment: @Harry I want the before element to cover the whole parent but not the text in the span , I want the text to be shown on top of that

Comment: @Mehran: Looks like you want something similar to what Anon has posted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`display:block; position:relative;` for `<span>` can help to you. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pQYK2/)

Comment: Do you have an idea on why position: relative is required? I'm trying to do something similar to what Mehran is asking, but the children of my outer div are much more than just a simple span, and setting position relative for each children would be a pain.

Comment: :before (with position:absolute) is flush with the span and cover him. Span msut have more z-index then :before but only blocks with relative, absolute or fixed can have z-index. You also can try use z-index:-1 for before in your variant.

Answer (score 1):

@Anon  answer worked for me

For people struggling with not wanting to apply "position: relative" to every single element, you can do

```
.outerDiv {
   > * {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 10;
   }
}
```

to apply the property to all direct children of the outerDiv.

Comment: Generally you should avoid using the `*` selector, because CSS works right to left, so it will have to test all elements on the page on that selector.